# Call <img title""> (or similar) into a div using javascript to display artwork and description?

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

To begin with a quick disclaimer: I'm new to javascript and not from a coding background but am currently working through books, tutorials and frequenting this very site to solve the problem by myself. However, I would very much appreciate some help on an image gallery with javascript functions.

The solution I need is for a thumbnail to link to a larger image on the same page with relevant text description displayed below it, using javascript. As the site is an artist's portfolio the goal would be for the artwork to be displayed with the title, dimensions and price below - while staying on the same page.

The current site http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/animals.html does this, albeit, without any script and at the expense of creating a separate page (purely down to my inexperience) for each image link.

The script I am currently experimenting with is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showImage(imgName) {
    var curImage = document.getElementById('currentImg');
    var thePath = 'images/animals/';
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;

    curImage.src = theSource;
    curImage.alt = imgName;
    curImage.title = imgName;
```

Visually this is the same as the existing website and works perfectly. However, I haven't a clue how I can bring in text specific for each image. I have tried to call in the `img title=""` as well as creating a div for each thumbnail to include `p` tags. Not practical! I have also attempted to create a `figcaption` but all that does is display under the thumbnail and throws everything out of alignment.

A gallery similar to what I am trying to achieve is at http://www.thekitchen.org/auction2010/#artwork. Outside of typing this post, I am trying to decipher the code as I am eager to learn javascript but am of limited time to solve this problem.

I would be indebted if anyone could kindly provide any pointers, solutions or advice.

Thank you.

---

I have since put to use both codes and am now toying with which one is appropriate for the site. Thank you all for your prompt answers and for taking the time to provide some fantastic support. I would like to give a vote up for both answers but as I'm a newbie, I have to wait until I am at 16 reputation. Nonetheless, I really can't thank you all enough.

Comment: Can you share your code that fails?

Comment: Absolutely! This is what I have been using for the past few minutes. Forgive my naiivity but I'm experimenting with anything and everything! `var titleDiv = document.getElementById('imagetitle');
        titleDiv.innerHTML = 'test';` is being used within the script and in the first thumbnail tag is `<div>
  <img src="images/animals/thumbs/chi.jpg" title="Leopard (coloured pencil)" alt="Leopard (coloured pencil)" onclick="showImage('chi.jpg');" /><p id='test'>It's not working...</p>
</div>`  Ideally I would like to display the title attribute, but from what I understand, this cannot be done.

Comment: Michal's answer seems plausible

Comment: Thank you for having a look at the code, Alexander. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to store the information within the image instead of a seperate data object:

```
<img src="img/gorilla_thumbnail.jpg" class="thumbnail" title="Gorilla" alt="Gorilla" data-price="$1000" data-description="Description about the item" data-full-image="gorilla.jpg" />
```

I would also recommend [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) (which has great documentation if you haven't used it previously) for dynamically updating the page when the user clicks on a thumbnail.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  // Following event will handle click to any img with class 'thumbnail':
  $('img.thumbnail').click(function () { 
    // 'this' will refer to the clicked thumbnail
    $('#mainImage').attr('src', 'folder/subfolder/' + $(this).attr('data-full-image')); // <img id="mainImage" /> to display full sized image
    $('#mainDescription').html($(this).attr('data-description')); // <p id="mainDescription"> or similar to display description
    $('#mainTitle').html($(this).attr('title')); // <p id="mainTitle"> or similar to display title
    // etc
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Graytest. I will have a go at doing the code provided by Michal, but will also use your code to get a better understanding of javascript. Thank you for taking the time to look at the code and provide a solution - I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Just implemented this code as well. For some reason I cannot call in the data for the price. I put `$('#price').html($(this).attr('data-price'));` after your line  `$('#mainTitle').html($(this).attr('title'));`. Regardless, this is also a great code for my needs. I simply need to weigh up which is more suitable for the site (it may end up being converted to WordPress in the future). Thanks once again - really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each image an id and later you want to use getAttribute("title") to retrive that attribute.  so for

```
<img src="../images/animals/thumbs/gorilla.jpg" id="gorilla" title="Gorilla (coloured pencils)" alt="Gorilla (coloured pencils)">
```

to get title of this image
you would do

```
g = document.getElementById("gorilla")
g.getAttribute("title"); // do what you need with the attribute
```

However it would probably be better to store extra data in an object indexed to ids in your html somewhat like this: (a jsfiddle is here

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" onclick ="showPicture('leopard');return false;"><img src="http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/images/animals/thumbs/leopard.jpg" title="Lone Leopard (
        watercolour)" alt="Lone Leopard (watercolour)" /></a>

        <a href="#" onclick ="showPicture('rhino'); return false;"><img src="http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/images/animals/thumbs/rhino.jpg" id="rhino" title="Rhino (coloured pencils)" alt="Rhino (coloured pencils)" /></a>
        <div><img src="http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/images/animals/leopard.jpg" id="full_picture">
        </div>
        <h1 id="main_title">Leopard</h1>
        <div id="description">
            Lone Leopard
        </div>
        <div id="price">
            $3,340
        </div>

        <script>
            var data = {
                "rhino" : {
                    "title" : "Lone Rhino",
                    "desc" : "watercolor",
                    "price" : "$3,340",
                    "full" : "http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/images/animals/rhino.jpg"
                },
                "leopard" : {
                    "title" : "Lone Leopard",
                    "desc" : "watercolor",
                    "price" : "$3,000",
                    "full" : "http://www.barrymckayart.co.uk/images/animals/leopard.jpg"
                }

            };

            function showPicture(id) {
                var main_image = document.getElementById("full_picture");
                var price = document.getElementById("price");
                var main_title = document.getElementById("main_title");
                var description = document.getElementById("description");

                main_image.src = data[id].full;
                price.innerHTML = data[id].price;
                main_title.innerHTML = data[id].title;
                description.innerHTML = data[id].desc;

            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

This has inline onclick events but, hey if the time is limited....

Comment: +1 to storing extra data. The model should be separated from the representation.

Comment: Thank you, Michal. I will implement this now to see how I get on. Thank you ever so much for taking the time to look at the code and provide me with a solution - I am really grateful.

Comment: I have just copied the code into the offline page and it works great. Thank you ever so much! Literally, this is day two for me having looked at Javascript. A little overwhelming, but indispensable nonetheless. I am unsure what you mean about inline onclick events and if this poses a problem, but I will look into. I will also look at Graytest's code, but again, thank you!

Comment: The inline events are not really a problem. Purists would argue that they are a bit outdated that's all.

Comment: Ah - ok. Thanks for letting me know, Michal. The code works fine, so that's good enough for me. Cheers!